# Which are the security procedures which we need to consider when we collect transaction signatures?

Tags: corda

Consider the following case:
node A builds and signs a TX which is sent to B for signing.

```
class FlowA(val otherParty: Party) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {

    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
        val notary = serviceHub.networkMapCache.getNotary()
        val builder = TransactionBuilder(notary)

        // ... add some commands and states

        val stx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(builder)

        val session = initiateFlow(otherParty)

        subFlow(SendTransactionFlow(session, stx))

        return session.sendAndReceive<SignedTransaction>(stx).unwrap {
            it.id == stx.id // is it enough?
            it
        }
    }
}

class FlowB(val session: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        subFlow(ReceiveTransactionFlow(session, false))

        val stx = session.receive<SignedTransaction>().unwrap {
            val ledgerTx = it.toLedgerTransaction(serviceHub, false)
            ledgerTx.commandsOfType<SomeContract.Commands.SomeCommand>().single()
            ledgerTx.verify()  // is it enough?
        }
    }
}
```

Is it secure to check only the id of the transaction from the sender side once we received the full signed transaction?

I've read in the doc that id is the root Merkle tree built by using transaction's components, so if the `otherParty` change something the id would be different, correct?

From the receiver side, is it secure to check which commands are present in the transaction so we are sure that the contract relative to that command is run by means of verify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On receiving a transaction, you will be able to interrogate all the inputs, outputs and commands.
Typically, the interrogation would happen inside the contracts verify method.

Yes, if anything were to change the root ID would indeed change. Note that it's not possible to change anything within a transaction once it has been signed.

Other things you could look for is the presence of the transaction being notarised.

It depends on what your contract needs to do, but yes, you would check which commands are present within a transaction e.g. in the issuance of a security, you might check that only one issue command is present.

You can also check the commands have received the required counterparty signatures.

If you would like to discuss in person, feel free to join one of office hour sessions - https://www.corda.net/support/technical-office-hours/